# How do I run existing Django site Linux setup on Windows while preserving versions of modules?

Tags: python, django, deployment

I have a site, built on Django/Python, which I need to profile. It's running on Ubuntu server with Apache, and I want to launch it on my local computer, under Windows on Django-dev-server.

The problem is that the site requires specific (outdated) versions of libraries, otherwise I will need to do many time wasting things to get it running (like migrations, dealing with changes of API in modules, etc).

So I basically need to build a version of Python interpreter on Windows, which will correspond to the version running on the Linux server - with all version of modules matching.

If there are no solutions for Windows, Linux also would be OK.

Kindly help!

Comment: So an your question is: "Could it make all by itself"?

Comment: @Denis Well... not "by itself", but in some level of automation - I would say.

Comment: just make simple text file and place records in it each on newline, like Django == 0.9.8 where first is name of package and last is version. After that install PIP and run pip install -r yourfile.txt

Answer (score 2):

Why not just run Linux as a VM in VirtualBox? If there is a requirements.txt file, it shouldn't be difficult to get running using pip to install modules, unless the versions of those modules aren't available anymore.

If the project is so old that the necessary modules aren't available, you're probably better off writing new code with updated modules.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the test lab as follows.

- The version of libraries and OS in virtual machine on windows or linux.
- For the version of python you can use a virtual environment.

> [The easiest way to configure](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Python#Installation) a custom Python environment is to setup a
>   "virtual environment" for Python using virtualenv. Virtualenv allows
>   you to add and modify Python modules without access to the global
>   installation.

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz
tar xzf virtualenv-1.5.2.tar.gz

python virtualenv-1.5.2/virtualenv.py $HOME/env
```

or

```
python virtualenv-1.5.2/virtualenv.py --no-site-packages --distribute $HOME/env
```

Comment: And how this can help OP ?

Comment: "I basically need to build a version of Python interpreter" --  "Linux also would be OK."   

if you need to install different versions of python [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv]